# How is the parity calculation in a RAID 6?

Tags: raid6

In a **RAID5**, the parity block is a ***XOR*** calculation of the rest of blocks but, in a **RAID6**, the second block parity is the ***XOR*** calculation of what blocks?

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/RAID_6.svg

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's not an XOR, more complex math is needed.  It's on the wikipedia page you linked that image from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#Computing_parity